# AWS EB - Deployment issue: Node.js version range >=16.0.0 is not available for this platform

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

am getting the following error:

```
2022/04/18 13:01:43.477894 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2022/04/18 13:01:43.901225 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2022/04/18 13:01:43.901248 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2022/04/18 13:01:45.648575 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786137 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786165 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786186 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786193 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install customer specified node.js version
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786197 [INFO] installing specified nodejs version...
2022/04/18 13:01:45.786575 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [Install customer specified node.js version]. Stop running the command. Error: the node.js version range >=16.0.0 is not available for this platform. Please choose a version matching one of the following: [v14.0.0 v14.1.0 v14.2.0 v14.3.0 v14.4.0 v14.5.0 v14.6.0 v14.7.0 v14.8.0 v14.9.0 v14.10.0 v14.10.1 v14.11.0 v14.12.0 v14.13.0 v14.13.1 v14.14.0 v14.15.0 v14.15.1 v14.15.2 v14.15.3 v14.15.4 v14.15.5 v14.16.0 v14.16.1 v14.17.0 v14.17.1 v14.17.2 v14.17.3 v14.17.4 v14.17.5 v14.17.6 v14.18.0 v14.18.1 v14.18.2 v14.18.3 v14.19.0 v14.19.1]
```

I am deploying on **Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.5.1**